# How to change to a different line of file in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a (badly written) long function of ifs and elses and whatnot that contains a for loop to look in a file at each line:

```
def check(low,high):
    with open('users.txt', 'r+') as followed:
        ts = time.time()
        sttime = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S - ')
        done_checking = open('done_checking.txt', "a")
        done = 0
        skippers = 0
        max_tries = 15
        for line in followed:
            if skippers==30:
                print "MAKE THE FOR LOOP GO BACK TO LINE 1 OF FILE"
            else:

                print "Does some other stuff"

                if done==max_tries:
                    sleep(randint(850,1150))
                    done = 0

                elif:
                    print: "SCRIPT DOES SOME STUFF!"

                else:
                    skippers += 1
                    print: "SCRIPT HAS SKIPPED A USER"
```

Is there a way that where it says

"MAKE THE FOR LOOP GO BACK TO LINE 1 OF FILE"

I can make the for loop reset to the first line of the file it is checking (users.txt) ?

(obviously, where it has print: "SCRIPT DOES SOME STUFF!", I have a lot of messy stuff happening with time stamps...)

Comment: try `fileobject.seek(0)`

Comment: This looks like a small file your reading in, @joep1, and then you could just read the whole file in one swoop, i.e., `followed.readlines()' and iterate over this array.  Then you can reset your counter to the first line simply by setting it to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "MAKE THE FOR LOOP GO BACK TO LINE 1 OF FILE"

Yep, you need to call seek function to get back to the line you want.

```
fileobject.seek(0)
```

This will get back to the line 1 of that particular file.